# SetInterval acting weird in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a canvas game, and I've been trying to use objects and methods to accomplish this. Right now i've run into a problem with it. It's kind of hard to explain. Basically there are a bunch of squares that are supposed to be moving around randomly. The method inside of the square object uses the setInterval method to move the square every 1/10 second. Every 10 seconds a new square is added. Once the new square gets added, the problems arise. All but 1 square move. The others get frozen (which they shouldn't). I hope I could explain it good enough, here are the problem areas.

```
function enemy(clr, cx, cy) {
    this.color = clr;
    this.cordX = cx;
    this.cordY = cy;
    this.move = function() {
        color = this.color;
        cordX = this.cordX;
        cordY = this.cordY;
        setInterval(function() {
            var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            switch (direction) {
                case 0:
                    if (cordX + 20 <= 480) {
                        context.clearRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                        cordX = cordX + 20;
                        context.fillStyle = color;
                        context.fillRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (cordX - 20 >= 0) {
                        context.clearRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                        cordX = cordX - 20;
                        context.fillStyle = color;
                        context.fillRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (cordY + 20 <= 480) {
                        context.clearRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                        cordY = cordY + 20;
                        context.fillStyle = color;
                        context.fillRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (cordY - 20 >= 0) {
                        context.clearRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                        cordY = cordY - 20;
                        context.fillStyle = color;
                        context.fillRect(cordX, cordY, 20, 20);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }, 100);
    }
}
```

and the square creator :

```
var newEnemy = new enemy("rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + ")", Math.floor(Math.random() * ((500 - 0) / 20)) * 20 + 0, Math.floor(Math.random() * ((500 - 0) / 20)) * 20 + 0);
newEnemy.move();
enemyNum = enemyNum + 1;
}, 10000);
```

You can look at it in action [here](http://testing.burritosquirrel.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how the movement gets increasingly more erratic with each square added?

You forgot to `var color, cordX, cordY` in your `this.move` function, meaning those variables are now global and each square is only working on whatever square was last instead of itself. This is why only one square moves.